# How can I add a series to a chart and then immediately delete it?

Tags: vba, excel

Charts in my Excel document do not update after I have made changes to them using VBA.

I remember from reading previously that it is possible to force charts to update by creating a new data series and then immediately deleting it again.

How can I do this in a way that won't throw errors or cause permanent damage to my charts?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a chart object named `chrt`

```
With chrt.chart.SeriesCollection
'Create a new series
.NewSeries
End With
With chrt.chart
'Delete the newly created series
.SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.Count).delete
End With
```